# ImportError ошибка при запуске скомпилированного cx_Freeze приложения PyQt

Tags: python, cx-freeze

Ситуация следующая. Написал на `Python 2.7` с использованием `PyQt 5.8` приложение, простенькое(таблички, автозаполнение из .json файлов, ничего необычного). Писал и тестил во время отладки в `Linux Mint 18.1`. Запускать приложение требуется в `Windows`, поэтому почитал про компиляцию в `exe`. Эпопею с установкой в `Win10` всех `sip`, `pyqt`, `qt` и `MSVC2015` приводить тут не буду, суть в том, что в итоге все поставил. Пробовал компилить через `py2exe`, `pyinstaller` и `cx_Freeze`. Уже не помню что были за проблемы, но получилось только с `cx_Freeze`. Приложение запустилось с экзешника и я, радостный, скинул его коллеге. Тот на домашнем компьютере(`Win10` без каких-либо `python`, `pyqt`, `qt`, `sip` и иже с ними) попробовал запустить - не получилось, вылезла ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py",
line 12, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py",
line 24, in <module>
File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
ImportError:DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

Я скинул на домашний ноут (`Win10`, тоже без начинки), все замечательно запустилось...
Сегодня на рабочем компьютере(`Win10`, `MSVC2015`, `pyqt`, `sip`, `qt`, `python 2.7`, но без `cx_Freeze`) тоже замечательно запустилось и работает. Скинул на соседний компьютер (`Win7`, без начинки) - та же ошибка.  Пришел коллега, которому скидывал в первый раз. На работе у него `Win7`, тоже без приблуд, скинул на его машину - ЗАРАБОТАЛО...
Вопрос, почему на некоторых машинах едет, а на некоторых нет? Почитал пару заметок, в них отмечали, что надо докидывать в папку нужные `dll'ки`, но ведь запускается же на некоторых, значит всего хватает. В чем может быть проблема?
Программированием начал заниматься чуть более месяца назад, так что, быть может, я что-то очивидное упускаю? Подскажите пожалуйста.
Подумал, что стоит скинуть содержимое import секции main.py из которого компилилось:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import os
from datetime import datetime
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QInputDialog, QTableWidgetItem, 
QAbstractItemView, QTableWidgetSelectionRange,\
QCompleter, QHeaderView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRegExpValidator, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRegExp, Qt, QStringListModel

from MainWindow import *
from EditWidget import *
from Dialog import *
```

Вот содержимое использованного **`setup.py`**:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Decimator",
    version = "0.3",
    description = "Decimator",
    executables = [Executable(script = "main.py", base = "Win32GUI")]
)
```

А [вот](https://github.com/Dogrtt/cx_Freeze_logfile/blob/master/log_cx_F.txt) лог из `CMD` при компиляции.

Comment: Почему Python2.7 используется? Вы вероятно хотите VS 2008 SP1 для Python 2.7 если не хотите свою сборку Питона поддерживать.

Comment: @jfs Не совсем понял про  VS, а 2.7 использую так как на кодакэдеми ветка 2 преподается. Куча примеров тоже для 2.7 (хотя, надо признать, что было пару раз, что для ветки 3, есть пример, а для ветки 2 нет.

Comment: Версии, собранные разными компиляторами могут быть несовместимы между собой.

Comment: @jfs Давно надо было сносить винду, и ставить новую, что я и сделал. На голой Win10 не запустилось, поставил MSVC2015, запустилось. Видимо какой-то .net или vc++ не стоит у этих ребят. Буду проверять завтра. Сейчас же, пробовал собрать все это дело pyinstaller'ом. Не получается ... Почему у всех в примерах и видео все огненно, все сразу встает, а как суть да дело у тебя, так все, туши  свет, кидай гранату...

Comment: Используя версию VS отличную от той с помощью которой ваша версия Питона собиралась, вы напрашиваетесь на неприятности. Тестировать можно в виртуальной машине (чтобы с известного состояния начинать и не повторять шаги без необходимости). Начните с двоичных сборок,  не компилируя самостоятельно. VC++ redistributable packages для вашей версии  поставьте. Обратите внимание на различия между 32 и 64-битными версиями (системы, самого Питона, отдельных модулей).

Comment: Возможно не хватает какой-то dll из новых обновленний Windows. Попробуте в VS поставить режим совместимости с XP или с Win7.